# How to load ORC table data into PIG variables

Tags: apache-pig

I'm pretty new to PIG programming, can we read or write data to Hive ORC table. Our requirement is to dump data from One hive ORC table to another ORC table, by doing some massaging of data in PIG script. Can any one share with me Samples for ORC reading or Writing. Please also share any quick learning sites of PIG.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = LOAD 'analysis.bic_orc' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```

I found this in Hortonworks website, I haven't personally used Pig to load ORC files.

http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/pig-is-much-slower-than-hive-when-reading-orc-files-using-hcatalog/

Hope this helps.